# How to get the scroll vertical and scroll horizantal for a page created in WPF

Tags: xaml, scroll

In the general XAML code, I have written as follows,

```
<pre>Page x:Class="UI_eHTMP.Window1" Title="eHTMP Application"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Height="800" Width="1400" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Title="applc1" Background="OldLace"&gt;</page></pre>
```

When I run the appliction and try to restore and Maximize the windows page, I don't see the task bar and vertical and horizantal scroll bars to scroll.

What needs to be included in the XAML code? Even the title is also not displayed when i have mentioned in the XAML title.

Answer (score 11):

Put your content inside a ScrollViewer.

```
<Page x:Class="UI_eHTMP.Window1" Title="eHTMP Application"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Height="800" Width="1400" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Title="applc1" Background="OldLace">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        // Content
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

If that doesn't work, remove the Width and Height properties from the Page, but keep the ScrollViewer.

As for the title, you've specified it twice, once as eHTMP Application and again as applc1. Try removing one of them.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, The horizantal and vertical scrolling is working.. but the title thing didnt work out. i removed one title from the xaml code.. but its not displaying the titlename on the top of the window.
Thanks
Ramm

Comment: If your page is being hosted in a NavigationWindow, take a look at this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fe824db3-d3ce-4fed-a297-a169c71af212